# The radius of convergence for the power series : $\ln x+\ln^{2}x + \ln^{3}x +\dots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I was tasked with finding the radius of convergence for the power series :  $$\ln x+\ln^{2}x + \ln^{3}x +\dots$$ the problem here lies in the fact that $\ln^{n}x$ has no $a_{n}$ part and so neither the d'Alembert criteria nor Cauchy can be applied. Also plugging $a_{n}=1$ is useless. How can this be evaluated? Should it be converted to Taylor, or integrated?

Comment: Power series do have radius of convergence since they always converge absolutely on a disc (and perhaps some boundary points). It is a consequence of $|x^n|=|x|^n$. But series that are not power series do not have to converge on a set of that shape.

Comment: However, if you replace $y=\ln(x)$ in your question, then the series becomes a power series $\sum_{n\geq1} y^n$. Solve the problem for that one, and the map the domain of convergence back to $x$-space using the inverse transformation.

Comment: That's not a power series. It's obvious that the series converges if and only if $|\ln x|<1$.

Comment: Well, if $\ln^n$ are powers, and not compositions.

Comment: It's not a power series, but it's a geometric series which converges when $|r|<1$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\ln x+\ln^2x+...=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\ln x)^k-1=\frac{1}{1-\ln x}-1$$
provided that $|\ln x|<1$ or equivalently $e^{-1}<x<e$. This follows from the geometric series.